# $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{K}[x,y,z]/\langle x^2-yz \rangle$ is normal and singular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{K}[x,y,z]/\langle x^2-yz\rangle$ an affine scheme. It is singular because only at the rational point $0$ corresponding to the ideal $\langle x,y,z\rangle$, the jacobian matrix has rank zero, so $\operatorname{dim} T_{X,0}=3$ and $\operatorname{dim} T_{X,x}=2$ in all the other points.

I know that the dimension of $\mathbb{K}[x,y,z]/\langle x^2-yz\rangle$ is $2$, but I can't prove it. However, my question is:

> I want to prove that $X$ is normal. In order to do this, I have built a ring homomorphism
>   $\phi: \mathbb{K}[x,y,z] \mapsto \mathbb{K}[Y,Z]$ sending $x \mapsto YZ$, $y \mapsto Y^2$ and $z \mapsto Z^2$. Then $\langle x^2-yz\rangle \subset \operatorname{Ker} \phi$. Is the homomorphism correct? How can I proof the reverse inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi: K[X,Y,Z]\to K[s,t]$ given by $\phi(X)=s^2$, $\phi(Y)=st$, and $\phi(Z)=t^2$. Let's prove that $\ker\phi=(Y^2-XZ)$.
Consider $f\in\ker\phi$, and divide this at $Y^2-XZ$ in $K[X,Z][Y]$. We get $f=(Y^2-XZ)g+r$ with $\deg_Yr\le1$. Then $r$ writes as $aY+b$ with $a,b\in K[X,Z]$. From $f(s^2,st,t^2)=0$ we get $a(s^2,t^2)st+b(s^2,t^2)=0$ and this entails $a=b=0$ (why?).

Now you can conclude that $\dim  K[X,Y,Z]/(Y^2-XZ)=2$ since it is isomorphic to $K[s^2,st,t^2]$, and $K[s^2,st,t^2]\subset K[s,t]$ is an integral extension. (Of course we can also provide some other arguments for the ring is $2$-dimensional.)

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{K}[s^2,st,t^2] \subset \mathbb{K}[s,t]$ is an integral extension, please?

Comment: @Federico $s$ is integral over $K[s^2,st,t^2]$ since it is a root of a monic polynomial: $X^2-s^2$. Similarly for $t$.

Comment: Is there any way to know whether the inclusion  $K[s^2,st,t^2]\subset K[s,t]$ is flat or not?

Comment: @NEMO Standard results on flatness imply that for this inclusion to be flat, we must have the induced map $K[s^2,st,t^2]\to K[s,t]_{(s,t)}$ flat. By exercise 18.18 in Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra" this map is flat if and only if $(s^2,st,t^2)$ is a regular sequence in $K[s,t]_{(s,t)}.$ Since $K[s,t]_{(s,t)}$ is a Noetherian local ring and $s^2, st,$ and $t^2$ are in the maximal ideal, the order of this sequence is irrelevant. Now, $st + (s^2)\in K[s,t]_{(s,t)}/(s^2)$ is visibly a zero divisor, so the sequence is not regular. Hence, the inclusion is not flat.