# Field of fractions of $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field. Then I want to know how to compute the field of fractions of $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$.

Note that by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147050/operatornamespec-mathbbkx-y-z-langle-x2-yz-rangle-is-normal-and-sing), $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ is isomorphic to $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz)$.

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R=k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ is a subring of the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$. Therefore the field of
fractions $F$ of $R$ can be considered as a subfield of $k(x,y)$, the field of rational functions of two variables. With this identification, $F=k(x^2,y/x)$ which is
a proper subfield of $k(x,y)$ but also isomorphic to $k(x,y)$.

Indeed, $F$ is the fixed field of the automorphism $\sigma$ of $k(x,y)$
defined by $\sigma(x)=-x$ and $\sigma(y)=-y$. Therefore $|k(x,y):F|=2$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence of 1st para. Why did you condider $F=k(x^2,~y/x)$ ? Next, what is the isomorphic map between $F$ and $k(x,y)$ ? Finally, how did you get the automorphisms $\sigma(x)=-x$ and $\sigma(y)=-y$? Please explain